# USB communication - FTD2XX.DLL with QT and MINIGW

Tags: qt, usb, ftdi

I am trying to use ftd2xx.dll, but something goes wrong.

I get this error

```
error: undefined reference to `_imp__
```

and I get the same error for the two first methods which use ftd2xx dll

```
undefined reference to `_imp__FTID_GetDllVersion@8'
undefined reference to `_imp__FTID_GetNumDevices@4'
```

those methods are in "FTChipID.h"

I have included ftd2xx.h and FTChipID.h

---

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ftd2xx.h>
#include <FTChipID.h>
```

---

**all header files (ftd2xx.h , FTChipID.h) and dlls (FTChipID.dll , FTD2XX.dll)
are in my project path.** , and I have done "Add Existing File" for header files.

Also I have added an includepath in .pro

```
INCLUDEPATH = C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\ftd
```

Comment: Why do you use it directly rather than using QtSerialPort or whatever interface you need?

Answer (score 0):

You won't need the FTChipID.h, at least we did not. We placed out libs in FTDI-Lib in Source folder. Place the dll version in $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/FTDI-Lib/dll, the include in $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/FTDI-Lib and add this to your LIBS in pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "FTDI-Lib"
LIBS += -L$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/FTDI-Lib/dll -lftd2xx
```

Comment: i have the same error. i create a path "FTDI-Lib/dll" in my project path and i place the FTD2XX.dll and ftd2xx.h together in the "FTDI-Lib/dll" path.

Comment: i have delete all methods which used from FTChipID.h, and now i use methods which contained only in dll. this is the programmers guide http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/ProgramGuides/D2XX_Programmer's_Guide(FT_000071).pdf i have the same error. in method:     ftStatus = FT_Open(0, &ftHandle); the error is undefined reference imp_FT_Open

Comment: Also add the lib file, this is not the static library but its required for linking to the dll. Put it right beside the dll.